# Login not working after setting cookies?

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security

Ive just set custom cookie values for my application with Spring.

On my web.xml I added this:

```
<session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <domain>.127.0.0.1</domain> I want to run my app in localhost:8949/administrator
            <path>/administrator</path>
            <secure>false</secure>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

So, the login form appears and I log in, creates the session but returns me to the login page.

I see 2 requests with differente `jsessionid`

one at j_spring_security_check and other at administrator/ and the request for the file `login;jsessionid=ASDF...`

My question, is this problem due a misconfiguration on my cookie? Could be that the specified path is not the correct? in that case, how can I specify the domain with a port? or the path is incorrect?

Any idea?